# Google Maps: Clickable Custom Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Upon creating many custom markers from within a loop, I cannot seem to find a solution to being able to link to external websites while each marker has a unique link.

I have tried many variations of this code, but seem to keep running into undefined variables (code below demonstrates undefined map_markers variable)

```js
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

            // generated by PHP, but output looks like this...
      var map_markers = [[43.536396, -110.740956, "T1", "/test-url"],[43.812092, -111.097181, "T2", "/test-url2"],[43.53640889360323, -110.74090051257326, "T3", "/test-url3"],[43.463373, -110.762519, "T4", "/test-url4"]];

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
       map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.8846194, -95.660041),
     zoom: 4,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });

       for (var i = 0; i < map_markers.length; i++) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {'lat': map_markers[i][0], 'lng': map_markers[i][1]},
      map: map,
      title: map_markers[i][2]
     });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(markers, index) {
            return function() {
                window.open("http://www.example.com/" . markers[index][3], '_blank');
            }
        })(map_markers, i));
    }

   });
  </script>
```

Note: The code above uses an enclosure, but i've tried many variations like adding a "url" param to the marker (but this results in the url property being undefined?), i've tried this.url when having that property too, but no luck...

Above code generates this error upon clicking a marker:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '135' of undefined** where 135 is the index number for the marker clicked

I have searched the web, but no solution seems to fix my problem. Maybe i'm missing something simple, but it's stumped me [?]

**PS: The map and markers generate perfect, just the JS error upon clicking a marker that i'm having issues with!**

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

```
window.open("http://www.example.com/" . markers[index][3], '_blank');
```

should be

window.open("http://www.example.com/" + map_markers[index][3], '_blank');

Comment: DOH. I feel so foolish. Knew it would be something I missed. That's what I get for mixing PHP and JS and not paying enough attention to syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Sure man, glad we figured it out!  Don't know if this is an option, but making an array of JSON objects instead of an array of arrays would make the JS code easier to understand and debug.  So instead of map_markers[index][3] it would be something like map_markers[index].URL or map_markers[index].Longitude